# Acumatica Grid Column Ordering

Tags: grid, acumatica

What is the secret to getting the columns order correctly in a grid. I have added a column to the Sales Order grid through the designer and placed it where I want it in the tree. It keeps being displayed as the last column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be as simple as resetting your saved column order as a user of the sales order page.

Under the Column Configurations > Click Reset to Default and see if this works...

[image]

Could also depend on other factors, but worth a try first.

Comment: Reset to default and republish customization will bring back factory/customization settings. After that it will follow user settings if they change column order.

Comment: Yep, for whatever reason this solves the problem. It is interesting though that it only affects 1 of my user defeined columns. The other 2 display correctly the first time.